# Combinatorial interpretation of the identity: ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, symmetry

What is the combinatorial interpretation of the identity: ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$?

Proving this algebraically is trivial, but what exactly is the "symmetry" here. Could someone give me some sort of example to help my understanding?

**EDIT:** Can someone present a combinatorial proof?

Comment: Excuse lack of my background, but I am curious about your second question. What do you mean by 'combinatorial proof'? Are you considering counting two different sets by a bijection? What do you have in mind?

Comment: That seems sufficient and like the correct approach. I especially just do not want to see the algebraic proof.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choosing $k$ objects among $n$ objects is same as leaving $n-k$ objects among $n$ objects.

(Notice that there is no essential difference between the words "choose" and "leave".)

---

Digression: I also consider this as one of the reasons why $0! = 1$ is a good definition.

Comment: I like the explanation with the words "choose" and "leave".

Answer (score 3):

$n \choose k$ denotes the number of ways of picking $k$ objects out of $n$ objects, and specifying the $k$ objects that *are* picked is equivalent to specifying the $n-k$ objects that are *not* picked.

---

To put it differently, suppose you have $n$ objects, and you want to partition them into two sets: a set $A$ of size $k$, and a set $B$ of size $n-k$. If you pick which objects go into set $A$, the number of ways of doing so is denoted $n \choose k$, and if you (equivalently!) pick which objects go into set $B$, the number of ways is denoted $n \choose n-k$.

The point here is that the binomial coefficient $n \choose k$ denotes the number of ways partitioning $n$ objects into two sets one of size $k$ and one of size $n-k$, and is thus a special case of the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) $${n \choose k_1, k_2, \dots k_m} \quad \text{where $k_1 + k_2 + \dots k_m = n$}$$
which denotes the number of ways of partitioning $n$ objects into $m$ sets, one of size $k_1$, one of size $k_2$, etc.

Thus ${n \choose k}$ can also be written as ${n \choose k,n-k}$, and when written in this style, the symmetry is apparent in the notation itself:
$${n \choose k} = {n \choose k, n-k} = {n \choose n-k, k} = {n \choose n-k}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 3 apples and you want to choose one of them.  Then you are left with an apple, which is the same, in a sense, as choosing that apple.

Comment: I cannot make any sense of this sentence.

Comment: I think he meant "...choose two of them."

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ elements. Choosing $m$ members of $S$ leaves a remainder of $n-m$ members in $S$.

Thus, each $m$-subset of $S$ corresponds to exactly one $(n-m)$-subset of $S$, and conversely, to any such $(n-m)$-subset, there corresponds exactly one $m$-subset of $S$.

Therefore, $\binom{n}{m}=\binom{n}{n-m}$.